# Is this set of vectors a subspace of $R^3$, find basis and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm working textbook problems and one of them is: Consider the set of the following form. Determine whether the set is a subspace of $R^3$. If it is, give its basis and dimension.
The set is $(a, a, a+3)$.

The constant in there is confusing to me. The book approach for something without that is to factor out a to get $a(1, 1, 1)$, and then this vector(s) $(1, 1, 1)$ can be used to determine whether find the span and linear independence. Is splitting into the vectors $a(1, 1, 1)$ and $(0,0,3)$ how you do this? Very confused. The book doesn't give any examples. If I do that, the dimension $= 2$, and I suppose the basis would be just those $2$ vectors. Is that the right approach?

Comment: How is $(a,a,a+3)$ a set?

Comment: Is $(0,0,0)$ in $\{(a,a,a+3):a \in \mathbb R\}$?

Comment: The way the book describes it, if you're given a general form like that, it's supposed to represent a set of all vectors. Then you can split it apart to find the span. I'm very new to vectors and linear algebra so it's all very confusing at the moment. Another example would be (3a, -2a, a) = a(3, -2, 1). And thanks geetha, I'm very sleep deprived and you just made me facepalm at myself. If you don't mind, what do I do if it passes that test like (a-4,0,12-4a)?

Comment: Forgot to explain, it says H is a set of vectors of the form (a, a, a), for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you are asking: let ${\bf R}^3$ be a vector space. Consider the set $H=\{(a,a,a+3): a\in {\bf R}\}$. Determine if $H$ is a vector subspace of ${\bf R}^3$. In case $H$ is a vector subspace, find a base and the dimension.

You mention that the constant (I suppose that "$a$" and if this is the case, it should be called "parameter") confuses you. So perhaps it is advisable to write the set $H$ in a different appearance, but of course, equivalents. Setting $x:=a, y:=a, z:=a+3$ with $a\in {\bf R}$ you can write $H$ as
$$H=\{(x,y,z)\in {\bf R}^3: x=a, y=a, z=a+3, a\in {\bf R}\}$$
One should always try to translate mathematics into a common language. In this case, we are saying that every vector $(x,y,z)\in {\bf R}^3$ belonging to $H$ must satisfy the conditions $x=a, y=a$ and $z=a+3$ for every real number $a$.

If we want know whether $H$ is a vector subspace, we can use the following characterization:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $H$ be a subset of $V$. Then, $H$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if and only if
> i) $H\not=\emptyset$.
> ii) For all $h_1,h_2\in H$, we have $h_1+h_2\in H$.
> iii) For all scalar $k\in F$ and $h\in H$, we have $kh\in H$.

We have $H$ is subset of ${\bf R}^3$ by definition. So, we need look at the conditions $i), ii)$ and $iii)$. The first question is : is $H\not=\emptyset$? To answer this question it is convenient (since every vector space has to have the zero vector) to determine if the zero vector $(0,0,0)$ is in $H$, that is just the comment given by geetha290krm. However for the vector zero to be in $H$ it must satisfy the condition imposed by $H$, then you must answer if we can write the vector $(0,0,0)$ as $$0=a, \quad 0=a,\quad 0=a+3$$
You can think about this a bit and eventually conclude that the vector $(0,0,0)$ is not in $H$. Therefore, the above theorem is not satisfied and we can then conclude that $H$ is not a vector subspace of ${\bf R}^3$ and since it is not a vector subspace, the other questions does not make sense.